# create _spf record against multiple ips

Tags: dns, spf

I want to create an spf record like this "_spf.google.com" so that I can add different IPs against this record. After creating this record i will not have to add different IPs in my spf section of my domains.

I want to create an spf record like this so that I can add multiple ips behind this record and I can add this record to any spf section of my domains:

"my.domain.com. 5   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com -all""

Please suggest how to create this sort of record.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not sure I understand the question.  But let me take a stab at it.

Assume you've got a couple of IP4 subnets from which you want to send emails.  Call them 203.0.113.0/28 and 198.51.100.0/32 (or just 198.51.100.0).  Then you can create a TXT record like:

```
_spf.domain.com. 5 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:203.0.113.0/28 ip4:198.51.100.0 -all"
```

Then if you want to send email from `mail1.domain.com` and `mail2.domain.com` you could just create records like

```
mail1.domain.com. 5 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com -all"
mail2.domain.com. 5 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com -all"
```

Then `mail1.domain.com` and `mail2.domain.com` will include the common IP list.  If later you add another IP - say 192.0.2.4, you could update the `_spf.domain.com` record to be:

```
_spf.domain.com. 5 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:203.0.113.0/28 ip4:198.51.100.0 ip4:192.0.2.4 -all"
```

and the IP list for both `mail1.domain.com` and `mail2.domain.com` would be updated.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

## How google does it

Gmail.com redirects to the `_spf.google.com`. Which is a different domain.

```
⟩ dig TXT gmail.com +short
"globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"
```

Google then includes all the records it needs and keeps the management somewhat simple with large complex records. It splits them up into their won thing `_netblocks.google.com`, `_netblocks2.google.com` etc.

```
⟩ dig TXT _spf.google.com +short
"v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"

⟩ dig TXT _netblocks.google.com +short
"v=spf1 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"
```

For different domains you use

```
dig TXT somedomain +short
"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.primarydomain"
```

For the primary, you stack your records into some organisation.

```
dig TXT primarydomain +short
"v=spf1 include:_exchange.primarydomain include:_smtp.primarydomain ~all"
```

Then put the actual addresses, etc.

```
dig TXT _smtp.primarydomain +short
"v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1/32 ip4:1.1.2.1/24 ~all" 

dig TXT _exchange.primarydomain +short
"v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1/32  ~all"
```